# Room & Paging: How to use multimap approach?

Tags: android-room, android-paging-3

With Room 2.4 we got the [multimap feature](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#multimap) which should according to the documentation prefered over intermediate data classes.

In my project I couldn't get this to work in combination with the paging library.

Example:

```kotlin
@Dao
interface DemoDao {

   @Query("""
      SELECT * FROM user U JOIN images I ON U.id = I.user_id
      WHERE U.id = :userId
      LIMIT 10
    """)
    fun getImages(userId: Long): Map<User, List<Image>>

    @Query("""
        SELECT * FROM user U JOIN images I ON U.id = I.user_id
        WHERE U.id = :userId
        LIMIT 10
    """)
    fun getPagedImages(userId: Long): PagingSource<Int, Map<User, List<Image>>> // this does not work!
}
```

How can I get use of the multimap feature or something similar with paging? I would like to use it because I see no other solution to limit the items in a one-to-many relation (in that case the `images`).

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve so I can better assist you? Your return type `PagingSource<Int, Map<User, List<Image>>>` looks like you want to display a list of maps, where each row is an entire map of Users to Lists of Images which seems like not what you want.

Comment: I want to display a paged list of users with there corresponding images but only 10 of them. I thought that I could use the 'Map' in a Paging source in the same way to get the Relation between User and their images as I would without paging. Hope that clarifies what I want to achieve :)

Comment: So it kind of sounds like what you actually want is a `PagingSource<User, List<Image>>`, basically a paginated list of Users, where each displayed row is their images. But did you also want the inner list of Images to paginate?

Comment: One issue is that Room only supports positional / Int keys, so you cannot have Room generate an item-keyed PagingSource for you directly, so I would probably recommend to just paginate the list of users directly, and then map those users to the List of Images ( assuming you don't want to also paginate the images). You can do this by getting a `PagingSource<Int, User>` from Room, and then using `PagingData.map` to transform each User into a data class that includes the User + the list of images.

Comment: Multimap is a separate feature in Room which won't really help you here, because you want to paginate over the users, not load them all at once. Otherwise you could just get the full map and display that in RV without pagination since Paging wouldn't buy you anything if you want to load everything at once.

Comment: I already thought about your suggested approach by remapping the PagingData. Should I use 'List<Image>' or 'Flow<List<Image>>' for the images in the mapped object. In my mind getting the images in second step would some kind of "block" the ui? With a flow I could respond to that image fetch in the ui. What is your recommendation about that? Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Are you trying to optimize for the cost of creating bitmaps or for the cost of fetching the image urls from DB? Either way you will not end up blocking the UI as both pagination and transforms are suspending / async

Comment: Ah good to know. I thought 'PagingData.map'  is blocking (How can it map the second item when the first is still in progress?). Then I will give it a try. Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: It will map one page at a time, but this happens asynchronously on a background thread and when the page is finished it is then sent to the UI to be displayed. You actually can control this since it is suspending, you can run the transform on whatever dispatcher you want using `withContext`